# worse case time complexity for binary search

Tags: binary-search

It is known that binary search takes t units of time in the worst case for a sorted array of size n. How long will the algorithm take in the worst case if input size is n/2?

Comment: Do you have a programming question?

Comment: this is a programming question.

Comment: Is there anything you tried? Can you share it? As you are relatively new, I strongly advice you reading our [Tour page](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and especially [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: can't you answer this?

Answer (score 0):

Our new input differs from the original input by a factor of 2. Because the worst-case time of binary search is known to have a logarithmic complexity, the asymptotic upper bound on the time should be the same. This should hold true for any input that's a multiple of 2 of the original.